# Windows Server 2016 Essentials folder permissions

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, robocopy, windows-server-2016, windows-server-essentials

We just installed a Windows Server 2016 Essentials machine and are trying to migrate from a Synology DS412+. I created users, created Server Folders for each of our network shares, and applied the appropriate permissions, all using the Windows Server Essentials Dashboard. I RDP'd into the server as an administrator and copied files over from the NAS to the server using:

```
robocopy <source> <destination> /E /COPYALL /R:2 /W:2
```

I am able to access all of the files with the individual users. However, we have an application that uses a Microsoft Jet database. Individual users are able to access the application, but when 2 users try to concurrently access the application we get an error:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'Q:\database\bysoft.mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data. (3051)

We do not have this issue on the NAS.

It appears that the issue is with permissions on the `.LDB` lock file generated by the database. The first user to open the application creates a `.LDB` file, but the second user is not able to write to that file.

How do I set the permissions to allow a user to write to another user's file? The first two users in the list are the ones trying to access the application (both have Read/Write permissions on the Server Folder).

[Server dashboard permissions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG99P.jpg)

**EDIT 1:**

Hopefully this screenshot helps answer some questions. This is the folder one level below the Server Folder, which contains the `.MDB` file:

[database folder permissions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRsIQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newly created files typically inherit permission from the parent folder.  You need to look at, and fix the permissions on the parent.  Unfortunately your screenshot is show us the sharing tab, which is probably fine.

The parent folder should grant modify access to a group that all users are a member of that will apply to the newly created files.

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the permissions on the parent folder. Could it be an issue with how permissions were copied over using `robocopy /COPYALL`?

Comment: Well more of a issue with the fact that POSIX ACLs aren't really 100% compatible with Windows ACLs.  Copying ACLs from a Synology, which I believe is *nix based, simply isn't going to be perfectly compatible with Windows.  You may have to redo your ACLs.

Comment: How do I apply the root folder's permissions to all files and subfolders contained within?

Comment: I had to take ownership of all files/folders (`takeown /f E:\ServerFolders\Bysoft6 /r /d y`) and reset permissions (`icacls E:\ServerFolders\Bysoft6 /reset /T /C /Q`).